# keyframe animation on load

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

So, I'm setting up some keyframe animations to animate content in on a one page AJAX site. The problem I'm facing is this. When the page loads, I want to have the main content block slide in from offscreen. It starts offscreen with `transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);` and my keyframes animate it to `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);`.

```
@keyframes aboutSlide {
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes aboutSlide {
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes aboutSlide {
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes aboutSlide {
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

    #about .content {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        animation: aboutSlide 1.5s ease-in-out 1;
        -moz-animation: aboutSlide 1.5s ease-in-out 1;
        -o-animation: aboutSlide 1.5s ease-in-out 1;
        -webkit-animation: aboutSlide 1.5s ease-in-out 1;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
    }
```

So, once the animation is complete, the content reverts to the original `transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);` which is definitely not what I want it doing. [Here](http://development.targetedthemovie.com/about) is a link to what I have right now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you can use `animation-fill-mode:forwards` this will stop the animation on the last frame.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Much appreciated!